# How can I customize equations numbering in subequations enviroment?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering, subequations

[image]

In the figure above, the subequations part of numbering is alphabetical, but I want to customize both the equation and the subequation part to look like this: `a-I`, `a-II`, and `a-III`. Here is the source code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}

\usepackage{subfloat}


\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}

    \begin{align}
        I_{sc} & = I_{sc,ref} & \hspace{-30 mm} \bigg[  1 + \frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \vspace{2 mm}
        \label{eq:I_sc_trans_STC2}
        \\
        %
        V_{oc} & = V_{oc,ref} & \hspace{-30 mm} \bigg[  1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \vspace{2 mm}
        \label{eq:V_oc_trans_STC}
        \\
        %
        P_{mp} & = P_{mp,ref} & \hspace{-30 mm} \bigg[  1 + \frac{\gamma}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \label{eq:P_mp_trans_STC}
    \end{align}

\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The env is not customizable. But it is simple, find the code for it in amsmath.sty and make your own version in your preamble

Comment: I removed the `cleverref` tag because the problem does not seem to involve the `cleverref` package at all (it's not loaded in the MWE). Feel free to rollback the edit if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{parentequation}--\Roman{equation}}
```

just after `\begin{subequations}`.

In the following MWE I've used `alignat` instead of `align` to avoid using text commands for horizontal space, and I've adjusted vertical space between equations using things like `\\[2mm]` instead of `\vspace{2 mm}\\`. Also text subscripts look better with `\text`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{parentequation}--\Roman{equation}}

    \begin{alignat}{2}
        I_{\text{sc}} & = I_{\text{sc},\text{ref}} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{\text{op}}-T_{\text{ref}}) \biggl]
        \label{eq:I_sc_trans_STC2}
        \\[2mm]
        %
        V_{\text{oc}} & = V_{\text{oc},\text{ref}} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{\text{op}}-T_{\text{ref}}) \biggl]
        \label{eq:V_oc_trans_STC}
        \\[2mm]
        %
        P_{\text{mp}} & = P_{\text{mp},\text{ref}} & \bigg[  1 + \frac{\gamma}{100} (T_{\text{op}}-T_{\text{ref}}) \biggl]
        \label{eq:P_mp_trans_STC}
    \end{alignat}

\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you need this behavior globally, i.e. `\alpha` numbering for all equations and `\Roman` numbering for all subequations, add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\subequations}{\alph{equation}}{--\Roman{equation}}{}{}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}
```

instead of using

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{parentequation}--\Roman{equation}}
```

each time.

Comment: Sorry, for my typo in the question. I did not mean changing the numbering to `a-I`, `b-II`, and `c-III`, but rather to `a-I`, `a-II`, and `a-III` meaning that is a set of equations `a` and its subequations are given in roman letters

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. The code now works as I want it to. I have edited the question to be more general. It is better to define a new command only once in the preamble and then use it later on instead of typing the full syntax over and over.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh I've rejected your edit because you've deleted some important improvements to the code (see `\text`).

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh I've added a global solution.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Glad it helps.